# Executing Commands at Cmd Prompt Result in "Access Denied"

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, uac

I am running Windows 7.

Whenever I try to run commands like 'ping', 'ipconfig', 'taskkill', 'tasklist', etc from the command line I get an "Access is denied" message.

I checked the "Advanced Security Settings" for the Windows\System32 folder and the Owner was set to "TrustedInstaller".  I changed the owner to "Administrators" but this did not seem to help.

Any ideas?  I was previously able to execute commands at the cmd prompt without issue.

Comment: Can you check that `c:\windows\system32\ping.exe` has Read and Execute privileges for Users in properties in the Security tab?

Comment: We faced the same issue with Windows 10 pro on 2 PC in different locations (different city)

Comment: we can run `cmd` as `administrator` and we can use `net user AnyAccount /active:yes`.  But using `route print` , `ipconfig /all` or any `Add/Remove programs` actions ends with permision /Access denied

Comment: Another interstning findings is that there is no way to normally run windows in `Safe mode`
The only way we found was to radically reset computer with unpluging power. Then Windows boot allows you to run in `Safe mode`  and then you have full access right. But only till you again run windows normally.

Any further help from community ?

Comment: We also did all the things from https://superuser.com/questions/1172307/windows-10-access-denied?rq=1

With no success.

Answer (score 0):

The user permission for the `c:\windows\system32\ping.exe` show that **Users** entry have `Read & Execute` permissions.  All other users have `Special` permissions.  I am not quite sure what this means.

Regardless, I performed a Windows Restore and that seemed to fix the issue. If anyone knows what could possible cause a problem like this please post.