# Windows 10 - access denied

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, uac

I am getting "access denied" on quite a few directories, spread over quite a few partitions.

In this case, I am trying to execute a program. I have previously had the problem when trying to create or delete a file.

> SETUP.EXE The system cannot execute the specified program.

I have tried:

- right click the folder, got to the security tab & set all permissions for everyone mentioned there : system/my account/administrators (which my account is).

  - I also tried a suggestion from a MS guy on an MS forum of adding "Everyone".
- takeown /r  /SKIPSL  /f `directory`
- icacls `directory` /T  /L  /Q /C /RESET
- control panel/users/set UAC level to lowest
- registry, set `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` to 0

I rebooted after each of those, and none helps.

I have Windows 10 home, so don't have access to the Policy Editor, if that might help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know how I can correct this problem?

Comment: Comments arn't for extended discussion [the comments have been moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52630/discussion-on-question-by-mawg-windows-10-access-denied)

Comment: A year later, I still have the problem. Probably time for a re-install, or a switch to Linux

Comment: Simply use the media creation tool to reinstall Windows without losing any settings, apps, or files. You can also reset your PC. Have you tried ```sfc /scannow``` to scan and repair corrupt Windows files? You can also use ```dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth```. Please note that both require elevated access to Command Prompt.

Comment: Thanks (+1) - "`Simply use the media creation tool to reinstall Windows without losing any settings, apps, or file`" - do you have a URL to explain how?

Comment: We faced the same problem. More info in related topic: https://superuser.com/q/373127/1049106

Answer (score 0):

You should try the "takeown" command, it lets you take ownership of a file/directory. If you want more info then just type "takeown /?" in the command line.

Source: http://windowsitpro.com/windows-vista/taking-ownership-file-or-folder-command-line

Comment: I tried it, to no avail :-(